# can plain old Remote Desktop be used to connect to Azure VM?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, remote-desktop, azure

Am new to Azure.
Added new VM.
To connect to it, have to open https://manage.windowsazure.com
and then do connect command.

Would like to save time and use good old Remote Desktop command from my physical Windows 7 Pro desktop computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-enable-remote-desktop/) in the documentation addressing this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can RDP to an Azure VM. If to set up a VPN between your Azure virtual network and your corporate LAN or assign a static, public IP for your VM(s), then you can RDP just like you usually would. I think both of those options involve an additional monthly fee (of course).

And don't forget to turn on remote access in the system properties of the VM and make sure the Windows firewall doesn't get in the way.

Comment: Ah, looks like ngn's answer does not involve paying for VPN or IP addresses, so that might be better for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. If you cloud service is named "foo", then you would need to connect to "foo.cloudapp.net". The port that you need to connect to will be some random port that was chosen at VM creation. You can see this port by looking at what external port in your Endpoint list points to the internal port 3389 of the target VM.

The Connect command is just a shortcut for doing the above. You can choose to save the RDP file and use it to connect in the future without redownloading the file. The information you need to connect is also available in that RDP file.